# Error trying to impersonate account when accessing google api (for my business)

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-my-business-api

I've been trying to access Googles Mybusiness API, but it seems a bit harder than the documentation states.

I have created a service account, that has access to everything I can think of, but still when trying to connection or access an API-resource, I get an error saying:

```
'Error:"invalid_request", Description:"Invalid impersonation prn email address.", Uri:""'
```

As far as I can tell, this indicates that the service account does not have permission to impersonate the account that is setup as administrator in Google My Business.

Almost every search result I find, mentions that the service account should be a G Suite Administrator. Neither the service account or the GMB administrator is in any G Suite-related setup, so even adding that permission to the service account has no effect.

How do I grant access to the API for the service account?

I have tried several methods to connect. Using the certificate was the only one where I was able to add a username, of the user I wish to impersonate:

```
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, p12FileName), "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        var initializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccount)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage" },
            User = user,
        };

        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer.FromCertificate(certificate))
        {
        };

        var myBusinessService = new MyBusinessService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        });
```

Comment: Please can you show the code you use to load the service account credential, and to call the API? Thanks.

Comment: @Chris, I have added a bit of code the to OP :)

Comment: thanks. I don't really know anything specific about GMB, but you can load a service credential from JSON, and set user and scopes: `GoogleCredential.FromFile(...).CreateWithUser(...).CreateScoped(...)`.

Comment: You may also find this thread helpful: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-My-Business-API/Scope-for-GoogleMyBusiness/td-p/551070#

Comment: thanks @Chris - the challenge here is that the client that google provides, https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples/, is using v1.10 of the google.api libs. The FromFile and CreateWithUser methods don't exist in that version.

Comment: Wow, 1.10 is a *really* old version! You should be able to add a direct reference from your project to Google.Apis.Auth v1.33.1 (the latest). v1.33.1 is meant to be compatible with v1.10, so it should work fine. Then you can use the FromFile and CreateWithUser methods.

Comment: @Chris I've to upgrade to v1.33.1, but still no luck

Getting an error message saying: 

`Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.", Uri:""`

Comment: Are you getting those error messages when using X509 certs, or from using FromFile and CreateWithUser in the new library?

Comment: @Chris either - when using the json or the p12 cert

The service account doesn't have access to impersonate the user account, but there is no way to give it access in the interface, other than was has been tried so far (as far as I can tell).